# JPA with Hibernate - object 'get' method returns different versions of one to one relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jpa

I have a User object with a one to one relationship with an AuthorizationToken object. The basis of this project can be found [here](http://porterhead.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/writing-rest-services-in-java-part-1.html)

When a user logs in, a new session is created by persisting an Authorization token linked to the user on a one to one basis, with a designated expiry time. For development purposes this expiry time was set to 1 month, and it was in the back of my mind. Now that my tokens have begun expiring the system is experiencing an error.

The following method is called when the user logs in:

```
public AuthorizationToken createAuthorizationToken(User user) {
    if(user.getAuthorizationToken() == null || user.getAuthorizationToken().hasExpired()) {
        LOG.debug("UserToken has expired or is null, creating new token");
        user.setAuthorizationToken(new AuthorizationToken(user, applicationConfig.getAuthorizationExpiryTimeInSeconds()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    return user.getAuthorizationToken();
}
```

This will return the current token, or a new one if it is null or expired. The token connected to the user is also replaced if null or expired (setAuthorizationToken method). This works, my new token is created in the DB and returned to the client.

We then use the token to create a request signature for each subsequent request. The server receives the signature, replicates using the stored token and checks they are the same to identify the sender.

Here is where the problem lies, the following is a method used to create the signature in the server:

```
private boolean isAuthorized(User user, AuthorizationRequestContext authorizationRequest, String hashedToken) {
    String unEncodedString = composeUnEncodedRequest(authorizationRequest);
    AuthorizationToken authorizationToken = user.getAuthorizationToken();
    String userTokenHash = encodeAuthToken(authorizationToken.getToken(), unEncodedString);
        if (hashedToken.equals(userTokenHash)) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

I am using the same user.getAuthorizationToken() method used in the original login process, but it produces two different values. The login method returns the newly created token, the signature service returns the first instance in the DB related to that user (which is now expired and should no longer be mapped to the user object). What is going wrong here? Is it just a matter of cleaning up expired tokens so they are not confused? I am sure it is a deeper issue as the user should only have one auth token mapping at a time.

any comments on code are appreciated.

Comment: How are you reading in the user and holding onto the contexts used to read the User?  EntityManagers are meant to be transactional contexts and maintain a cache of managed entities they were used to read in.  If you keep it around, any changes made in other contexts will not be visible in long lived EntityManagers without they first be cleared or the entities refreshed.

Comment: just wanted to add to this that yes this was also a problem. Adding the @Transactional annotation to the method ensured the changes were committed to the database. (repository.save was not performing the DB commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I think is happening.

Looking at the source code, in `AuthorizationToken` you have a mapping to `User` (this is the owning side of the relation)

```
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private User user;
```

And in `User` you have the other side of this relation

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "user",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private AuthorizationToken authorizationToken;
```

When you create new token in `createAuthorizationToken()`, you only set that new token into `user` and saving changes on user. You are not setting `null` user on the old token. After this, since `AuthorizationToken` owns the relation (foreign key is in its table), you end up with two rows in `rest_authorization_token` table, both having `user_id` pointing to your user. This means that token returned with user is the one that database returns as the first one, which can be different between calls, resulting in you seeing different token instances in different methods.

The solution is to either set `null` to the old token or delete the old one completely. This being a `@OneToOne` relation, you should have a unique constraint on `rest_authorization_token.user_id`. Something like this

```
public AuthorizationToken createAuthorizationToken(User user) {
    if(user.getAuthorizationToken() == null) {
        LOG.debug("UserToken is null, creating new token");
        user.setAuthorizationToken(new AuthorizationToken(user, applicationConfig.getAuthorizationExpiryTimeInSeconds()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    } else if (user.getAuthorizationToken().hasExpired()) {
        LOG.debug("UserToken has expired, creating new token");
        AuthorizationToken oldToken = user.getAuthorizationToken();
        oldToken.setUser(null);
        tokenRepository.update(oldToken);
        user.setAuthorizationToken(new AuthorizationToken(user, applicationConfig.getAuthorizationExpiryTimeInSeconds()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    return user.getAuthorizationToken();
}
```

Comment: awesome! thank you. There are two tokens being created, your suggestion works perfectly